# Error al intentar utilizar go_router con BottomNavigationWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

Me encuentro realizando unas practicas con go_router y estoy intentando utilizar BottomNavigationWidget para navegar entre diferentes vistas pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es que almomento de ejecutar la aplicacion en debug funciona medianamente bien, pero si utilizo la app descargada no navega hacia ningun lado, este es el main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'config/app_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}
```

Estas son mis rutas:

```
import 'package:bops_app_v3/screens/add_screen.dart';
import 'package:bops_app_v3/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:bops_app_v3/screens/product_screen.dart';
import 'package:bops_app_v3/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

final router = GoRouter(routes: [
  GoRoute(
    path: '/',
    builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: '/product',
    builder: (context, state) => const ProductScreen(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: '/add',
    builder: (context, state) => const AddScreen(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: '/profile',
    builder: (context, state) => const ProfileScreen(),
  ),
]);
```

Este es mi BottomNavigationWidget:

```
import 'package:bops_app_v3/config/app_router.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class BottomNavigationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomNavigationWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      onTap: (index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            context.go('/');
            break;
          case 1:
            router.go('/product');
            break;
          case 2:
            context.go('/add');
            break;
          case 3:
            context.go('/profile');
            break;
        }
      },
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label: 'Home'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.production_quantity_limits_outlined),
            label: 'Product'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined), label: 'Add'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_2_outlined), label: 'Profile'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Y estas son mis vistas, todas son iguales solo cambia el body:

```
import 'package:bops_app_v3/widget/botton_navegation_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Text('Home screen'),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavigationWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uso ShellRoute para ingresar las rutas que deben ir con la barra de navegacion. y ademas dos NavigatorKey para cada grupo de rutas, las que tienen bar y las que no.

Mira mi codigo puede que te sirva:

```
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

var routesGo = GoRouter(
  debugLogDiagnostics: false,
  navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
  observers: <NavigatorObserver>[FBAnalytics.observer],
  initialLocation: NamesRoutes.signIn,
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return ScaffoldWithNavBar(child: child);
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
          name: NamesRoutes.home,
          path: NamesRoutes.home,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            child: PrincipalPage(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
          name: NamesRoutes.billing,
          path: NamesRoutes.billing,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            child: const BillingPage(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
          name: NamesRoutes.payPartialTax,
          path: NamesRoutes.payPartialTax,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            child: PayPartialTaxPage(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
          name: NamesRoutes.emitirFactura,
          path: NamesRoutes.emitirFactura,
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const EmitirFacturaPage();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
      name: NamesRoutes.signIn,
      path: NamesRoutes.signIn,
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return SignInPage();
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
      name: NamesRoutes.setNumber,
      path: NamesRoutes.setNumber,
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return SetNumberPage();
      },
    ),
    ....]
```

main.dart

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc.instance,
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => HomeBloc.instance,
        ),
      ],
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => AppLocale(),
        child: Consumer<AppLocale>(
          builder: (context, locale, child) {
            return MaterialApp.router(
              title: 'AppName',
              theme: AppTheme.light,
              locale: locale.locale,
              routerConfig: routesGo,
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
              localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class ScaffoldWithNavBar extends HookWidget {
  const ScaffoldWithNavBar({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        body: child,
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(
              CustomIcons.emitirfc,
              color: ColorTheme.VioletaOscuro,
            ),
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: ColorTheme.VerdePrimario,
            onPressed: () {
              routesGo.pushNamed(NamesRoutes.emitirFactura);
            },
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBarCustom(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavigationBarCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomNavigationBarCustom({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavigationBarCustom> createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarCustomState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarCustomState extends State<BottomNavigationBarCustom> {
  int _locationToTabIndex(String location) {
    final index =
        tabs.indexWhere((t) => location.startsWith(t.initialLocation));
    return index < 0 ? 0 : index;
  }

  int get _currentIndex => _locationToTabIndex(GoRouter.of(context).location);

  void _onItemTapped(BuildContext context, int tabIndex) {
    if (tabIndex != _currentIndex) {
      routesGo.push(tabs[tabIndex].initialLocation);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: BottomAppBar(
        notchMargin: 1,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
        height: 70,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: ColorTheme.VioletaPrimario,
        elevation: 0,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          unselectedItemColor: ColorTheme.white,
          fixedColor: ColorTheme.VerdePrimario,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          onTap: (index) => _onItemTapped(context, index),
          items: tabs,
          selectedFontSize: 11,
          unselectedFontSize: 11,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScaffoldWithNavBarTabItem extends BottomNavigationBarItem {
  const ScaffoldWithNavBarTabItem(
      {required this.initialLocation, required Widget icon, String? label})
      : super(icon: icon, label: label);

  /// The initial location/path
  final String initialLocation;
}

List<ScaffoldWithNavBarTabItem> tabs = [
  ScaffoldWithNavBarTabItem(
    initialLocation: NamesRoutes.home,
    icon: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 2),
      child: Icon(
        CustomIcons.home,
        size: 26,
      ),
    ),
    label: "Home",
  ),
  ScaffoldWithNavBarTabItem(
    initialLocation: NamesRoutes.billing,
    icon: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 2),
      child: Icon(
        CustomIcons.facturacion,
        size: 26,
      ),
    ),
    label: "Facturación",
  ),
  ScaffoldWithNavBarTabItem(
    label: "Emitir Factura",
    icon: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, bottom: 2),
      child: Text(""),
    ),
    initialLocation: NamesRoutes.emitirFactura,
  ),
  ScaffoldWithNavBarTabItem(
    initialLocation: NamesRoutes.payPartialTax,
    icon: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 2),
      child: Icon(
        CustomIcons.impuestos,
        size: 26,
      ),
    ),
    label: "Impuestos",
  ),
  ScaffoldWithNavBarTabItem(
    initialLocation: NamesRoutes.menu,
    icon: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 2),
      child: Container(
        height: 26,
        child: Icon(
          CustomIcons.hamburguesa,
          size: 16,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    label: "Menu",
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

veo que algunos routes los llamas mediante tu router y otros mediante contexto.... estará allí el problema?

```
switch (index) {
          case 0:
            context.go('/');
            break;
          case 1:
            router.go('/product');
            break;
          case 2:
            context.go('/add');
            break;
          case 3:
            context.go('/profile');
            break;
        }
```